# CustomRepositoryImpl for Spring Data JPA Showing "Never Used" in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, jpa, intellij-idea, repository

I created a custom implementation of a repository using the Spring Data Annotations and autowiring. The base repository interface is below and is controlled by Spring annotations.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface BasicRepository extends JpaRepository<BasicMaster, Long>, BasicCustomRepository {}
```

The custom repository interface is:

```
public interface BasicCustomRepository{
    List<BasicResponse> getBasic(BasicRequest basicRequest);
}
```

and the custom repository implementation is:

```
public class BasicCustomRepositoryImpl implements BasicCustomRepository {
///CODE
}
```

This code works as expected but for some reason, IntelliJ says "Class BasicCustomRepositoryImp is never used". How do I get IntelliJ to recognize that this is an implementation of a used interface?

Comment: Looks like a bug with the inspection, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and share a sample to reproduce it.

Comment: Found the solution. The custom repository and the implementation must have a Spring type annotation. In this clase, @Repository. Spring is then able to correctly identify it and use spring based bean injection (which it wasn't using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the custom repository and the implementation must have a Spring type annotation. In this case, @Repository. Spring is then able to correctly identify it and use spring based bean injection. so

```
@Repository
public interface BasicCustomRepository{
    List<BasicResponse> getBasic(BasicRequest basicRequest);
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public class BasicCustomRepositoryImpl implements BasicCustomRepository {
///CODE
}
```